# Formatting html numbers with commas

Tags: javascript

I have an email template, whose number has will be passed from the backend, and it should display the number in 1,000,000 format.

The template does not have `<input>` tags, but is simply displayed as below -

```
<br>
Your account currently has<strong>&nbsp;{{value}}</strong><strong>&nbsp;</strong>points
<br>
```

I went through this article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/comma-values-in-numbers/ but i'm not sure how can i pass the value to the javascript function, and then back to the html.

I played a little with the code, but i'm not able to pass the values right, or maybe something else.
Sorry, i'm not a javascript guy. Any help please?

Many thanks!

> Update - Could not find a solution, so we decided to go with the
>   backend,

Comment: You are trying to change your {{value}} from javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you want to format 'value' using a javascript function? Are you using an stand-alone templating engine?

Comment: You could do this directly from backend. Any reason for doing it in js? (Sounds like you want to send JavaScript in an email?)

Comment: Hi, the provider we're using is sparkpost. And i was told that it was better to perform this on here, after the value is received from the backend. Is there a way that i can read the {{value}} in html, then pass it to javascript to process, and then send it back to html to display?

Comment: ..we decided to go with the backend, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a comma after every third digit from the end?

```
Var newFormattedValue = "";
Var str = yourvaluehere.toString();
for(var i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    newFormattedValue += str[i];
    if (i % 3 == 0) newFormattedValue += ",";
}
```

Then just reverse the newFormattedValue with a for loop and it should be done